# console log a reactive prop in lwc

Tags: salesforce, svelte, apex, lwc

Hello I am learning salesforce and the documentation is sometimes vague for lwc. I am coming from svelte / react and I want to console log the value of a variable being passed down from parent to child. The syntax is not clear to me.

I think @api is basically like exposing a variable as a prop. But do I use @wire or getter  to simply log changes to a variable?

```
    export let disabled; <--svelte
    @api disabled;<--salesforce


    $: console.log(disabled)<--svelte
    what is equivilent??? <--salesforce
 
What is the equivilent of doing $: console.log(this.disabled) from svelte to log reactive changes?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard about svelte before but

Try not exposing the real variable `@api`. Instead have a normal variable (there's convention of prefixing "privates" with an underscore but it doesn't have any power, doesn't change anything in access rules) and expose a getter/setter and then in setter you could inject any side effects you want?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-props-getters-setters.html

https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/todoList/todoList.js

There's even school of thought (eslint code smell rule) that says if you exposed something as @api you shouldn't modify it directly yourself. Don't treat it like an oracle but seems 1 more use case for getter / setter. https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc/issues/91#issuecomment-1709204840

Comment: perfect! I wasn't sure what it was called and I think @track was the private one. So im actualy thinking of setting the variable in the parent component, then passing it down to the child

Comment: That's OK. LWC uses passing params (to `@api` variables or setters) for top-down. And (bottom-up) children notify parents stuff happened by emitting events. So try with an @api annotated setter?